# What does the Evolution "Flagged" column represent?

Tags: evolution

I've only today, started to use Evolution.

What does Evolution's **Flagged** column indicate?
The Flagged column is the third one from the left in the Mail window of the default setup.  Its icon is a red exclamation-mark in a red circle.

I find lots of references to the fact that it is a sortable column, but nothing to indicate what its function is.

I've noticed that an **un-deleted** message (from the Trash) shows as **Flagged**, but the word "flagged" can suggest that something is currently **pending**?

I've been experimenting, and now have several **Flagged** messages. I am reluctant to close Evolution, until I know exactly what it means.

**PS.** The **Flagged** column is not the same as the **Flag Staus** column. The **Flag Status** column's icon is a **Flag**... The names are confusing, and as I mention in a comment below, I've been through the Help, but have not found a definitive answer.

---

Here is a screenshot of the column-headers, and their names (in the customize dialog).

[image]

Comment: The 'Flagged' field works the same way as the 'starred' field works in gmail.
Thus it is used  as a visual reminder that you need to follow-up on a message or conversation later.

Comment: I don't know exactly how the "starred" field in gmail works, but in Evolution there are 2 "columns/fields"  with the word "Flag" in them...  "Flagged"  and  "Flag Status"

Comment: PS.. It is all resolved in Aneeshep's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is same as the 'starred' in gmail. Used to mark important mails.

Comment: Aneeshep, thanks for the answer. You have prompted me to look at this issue again (after 4+weeks)... It's finally sorted out...  The 3rd column, **"Flagged"** = *"Important / Unimportant"* (in the context-menu)... 
The 4th column in my pic, **"Flag Statuses"** is activated by the context-menu's *"Mark for follow-up"* and by then choosing from approximately 10 flags. This displays a Flag-Status of "To Do (Red-ish)" or "Completed (Green-ish Flag)" and finally blank (Cleared).

Answer (score 5):

It's basically just a marker for your own reference, so you remember to come back to it later. You can read more about this and other features of evolution in the User Guide.

[Evolution User Guide: Web](http://library.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/)

[Evolution User Guide: PDF](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/doc/evolution24.pdf)

These are both up to date for the latest version (2.3).

Comment: Actually, the Web help was the first place I looked. I used its seach box "Flagged", and also searched Google via "library.gnome.org: Flagged"... First of all, the word "flagged" seems to refer to different things... eg. In the online Help, it referred to "flagged" in realation to "Flag Status", but this is an entirely different column. It is the one to remind me to "come back" (as you put it)... The "Flagged" column is still a mystery. Basically, in both the online and pdf help. I've found only single-word references to "Flagged". There is no definitive reference to it as a column header.